# Earning badge by filling about ABOUT ME

Tags: support, badges

I tried many times to earn the badge you get by completing the About Me section in my profile. Well, I have done so but still have not earned the badge.

Can you please let me know what I am missing? Does the About Me section require an image or certain styling to be considered complete?

Comment: The FAQ has a separate [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232) to address this (disclaimer: I wrote the original version).